# c3p0 compatibility with jconnect 4

Tags: prepared-statement, sap-ase, c3p0, sqlanywhere, jconnect

I am trying to upgrade from jconn2 to jconn4. The issue that i am facing is that c3p0 is notworking as expected. Quick online search says that it supports jconn4 completely, but i get the below exception.

```
com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -685: Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4003)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3093)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:78)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:289)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:271)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java:2408)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:2394)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:257)
```

Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue??/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is too many prepared statements open, relative to [max_statement_count](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbadmin_en11/max-statement-count-option.html) defined on your server.

The simplest thing to do would just be to turn Statement caching off in c3p0, i.e. make sure that the c3p0 properties `maxStatements` and `maxStatementsPerConnection` are set to 0. If you want the performance benefits of statement caching, make sure that `maxStatements` is set to a value significantly lower than the server-side `max_statement_count`. You could also turn the "resource governor" off by setting `max_statement_count` to zero, although Sybase seems to discourage that.

See also [c3p0 docs re Statement caching](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling).

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why it works fine when i use jconn2 but doesn't work when jconn4 is used?

Comment: i don't know enough about Sybase's drivers (or backends) to be able to say.

Comment: Please see http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/25804/sql-anywhere-error-685-resource-governor-for-prepared-statements-exceeded